# Folding AA after the flop?

Tags: nlhe, tournament, betting-strategy

Hero in BB hits AA before the flop. BB is $600, there are 3 or 4 callers (I'm old and can never recall all the details), and hero doesn't like to see his AA busted by a runner-runner so he raises $3000. Villain (OTG) calls but everyone else folds. The flop is 10xJxQx (rainbow with inside straight draw), hero bets another $3000, villain pushes. Hero doubts villain flopped straight based on call before the flop. Hero puts him on pair, 2 pair, or a possible set but hero only has about $12K left and calls. Good call?

Epilogue:

> Turns out villain only had one J so the flop only gave him a pair of Jacks but the river gave him a JJJ and the pot.

Comment: good call, bad raise size on the flop

Comment: Usually, a BB special refers to when a player in the BB has a trashy, often unplayable hand, and is fortunate to see a flop, where they hit a very strong, disguised hand. It's not meant to refer to good hands and common scenarios ;D

Comment: Removed incorrect BB special ref

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you had an 18K stack preflop, or about 30bbs. The 3K raise is fairly standard, though you shouldn't only raise that size with hands like AA because perceptive opponents can figure that sort of thing out if they play enough hands with you (then again, if no one at your table is perceptive, go ahead and play in an exploitable way).

On the flop the pot is about 6900 so your 3K is a tad too small. I'd go for at least 4200 or so. And you should never fold after making that bet, you simply aren't deep enough, he'll value shove lots of worse hands, and he can easily have draws (or potentially air) as well. So yeah, you've got to call here with these stack sizes.

P.S. Don't post results, or at least don't post them this early. They'll have an influence on the responses you receive and you don't want that.

Comment: I don't see any fault with betting 3K on the flop, as pretty much any bet should mean that Hero is committed to an All-In, which I think is best. That said, inducing a raise from villain then becomes a good thing, so 3K or even less as a cbet is reasonable I think.